# java.lang.String com.example.smartappfirebase.counters.getCounter()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> Firebase Structure
>   [image]
>
> Devices class:

```
public class Device{

private String title;
private counters counters;

public Device(){}

public Device(String title,counters counters) {
    this.title = title;
    this.counters = counters;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public counters getCounters() {
    return counters;
}

public void setCounters(counters counters) {
    this.counters = counters;
}
```

}

> counters class

```
public class counters implements Serializable {

private String counter;
private String countername;
private String maitenance;

public counters (){

}
public String getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public void setCounter(String counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}

public String getCountername() {
    return countername;
}

public void setCountername(String countername) {
    this.countername = countername;
}
public String getMaitenance() {
    return maitenance;
}

public void setMaitenance(String maitenance) {
    this.maitenance = maitenance;
}

public counters(String counter, String countername, String maitenance){
    this.counter=counter;
    this.countername=countername;
    this.maitenance=maitenance;
}
```

}

> Second class Counters Class My Problem is I don't know how to read counter object from the database with
>
> ```
> FirebaseUI
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> RecycleView
> ```
>
> , because null object reference, magic here are come

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    displayDevices();
    return view;
}
private void displayDevices(){
    options=
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Device>()
                    .setQuery(databaseReference.child("devices").orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(userid),Device.class).build();


    adapter=
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Device, MyRecyclerViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Device model) {

                    holder.txt_title.setText(model.getTitle());
                    holder.txt_counter.setText(model.getCounters().getCounter());

                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public MyRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.device_list,parent,false);
                    return new MyRecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
                }
            };

    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    adapter.startListening();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

> Here is my Error Block from Android Studio
>   [image]
>
> I try all day search solution, i am newbire in android development, but i try to do my best.

Comment: `model.getCounters()` is null. Check for that.

Comment: Update: this problem solved, new one is  `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.smartappfirebase.counters `

Comment: Because this question is now the same as the previous one, I've marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: okey, but still not found my solution :( I dont know how to make this object to arraylist